# How do I assign values into different buckets to make histogram in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, histogram

In PostgreSQL and Oracle I can make histograms based on buckets using this syntax for my case:

```
select department_id, 
       last_name, 
       salary, 
       width_bucket(salary,0,150000,10) 
from employees
```

Is there an alternative way for me to assign values to buckets in MySQL?

Comment: `width_bucket` is common integer division by fact. So in MySQL you may use DIV operator.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the suggestion, I tried the DIV operator and the ntile function as well. Both seem to work well for me to partition values into different buckets.